# The meaning of "publicity blitz" in this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Thus, in the Spring of 2017, just as The New York Times began a
>   **publicity blitz** that touted its commitment to the truth ("Truth: it
>   needs your support") and that would greatly boost its number of online subscriptions, it headhunted Bret Stephens, a climate-denialist
>   op-eel writer, from The Wall Street Journal - all in the name of
>   editorial 'balance" (presumably between facts and non-facts).

Comment: Any prior research. Dictionary definitions?

Answer (score 1):

The word "blitz" is used glibly to describe an *intensive campaign*. It refers to "the Blitz", which was a heavy bombing campaign during World War II. The word is German for "lightning" and so when used in a modern sense, speed is implied as well as intensity - a lot of work condensed into a short period of time. For example in British English "blitzing the kitchen" could mean cleaning the kitchen very quickly but thoroughly.

A "publicity blitz" would be an *intensive* publicity campaign.

Comment: And what is the meaning of "intensive publicity campaign"? Does it mean "an intensive campaign for advertisement"?